# how to pass id from a form in html using nodejs mysql

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Here is the html form through this I can input the client id through the dropdown and I want to use that client id which come from the dropdown to pass through the form:

```
<form action="/query" method="get">

        <!-- <label>Client ID</label> -->
         <select name="client_id" required="">
            <option disabled selected value> -- select a Client  -- </option>
            <%for(i=0; i<clients.length; i++){%>
                <option value="<%= clients[i].id%>"><%= clients[i].client_name %></option>
            <%}%>
        </select>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and here is the get function:

```
    // Query
app.get('/query', function(req, res){
  /*  var client_id = {
        client_id:req.body.client_id,
    };*/
    db.query("SELECT * FROM regions WHERE client_id = client_id  ",function(err, result){
        if(err) throw err;
        //console.log(rows); 
        console.log(result);
        res.render('query_areas',{result:result});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a `GET` request, the client id is accessible as `req.query.client_id`.

To pass it to the SQL query, you can use a [query placeholder](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#performing-queries):

```
app.get('/query', function(req, res){
  db.query("SELECT * FROM regions WHERE client_id = ?", [ req.query.client_id ], function(err, result) {
    if(err) throw err;
    //console.log(rows); 
    console.log(result);
    res.render('query_areas',{result:result});
  });
});
```

If you want to use `POST`, you would use `req.body.client_id` instead (make sure that you also use a body parser middleware like `body-parser`, `express.json` and/or `express.urlencoded`), otherwise `req.body` won't be created).

Comment: By the way Sir if it is post request then what Should I do?

Comment: @LambdaTheta I updated my answer to include instructions for `POST` requests.

Comment: Thanks alot once again for your support.